# Looking for a pandas function analogous to DataFrame.nafill()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I would like to apply a function that acts like `fillna()` but takes a different value than nan. Unfortunately `DataFrame.replace()` will not work in my case. Here is an example: Given a DataFrame:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,-1,-1],[5,6,-1]])

       0    1    2
    0  1  2.0  3.0
    1  4 -1.0 -1.0
    2  5  6.0 -1.0
    3  7  8.0  NaN
```

I am looking for a function which will output:

```
       0    1    2
    0  1  2.0  3.0
    1  4  2.0  3.0
    2  5  6.0  3.0
    3  7  8.0  NaN
```

So `df.replace()` with `to_replace=-1` and `'method='ffill'` will not work because it requires a column-independent `value` which will replace the -1 entries. In my example it is column-dependent. I know I can code it with a loop but am looking for an efficient code as it will be applied to a large DataFrame. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Your example seems like it would work if you replaced -1 by nan and then ffilled.  Could you give an example where it wouldn't?

Comment: Yes, in case there are is a mix of -1 and nan in the DataFrame. I will add an edit for that case

Comment: Added it @DSM, please see the edited question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just replace the value with `NaN` and then call `ffill`:

```
In [3]:

df.replace(-1, np.NaN).ffill()
Out[3]:
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  2  3
2  5  6  3
```

I think you're over thinking this

**EDIT**

If you already have `NaN` values then create a boolean mask and update just those elements again with `ffill` on the inverse of the mask:

```
In [15]:    
df[df == -1] = df[df != -1].ffill()
df

Out[15]:
   0  1   2
0  1  2   3
1  4  2   3
2  5  6   3
3  7  8 NaN
```

Another method (thanks to @DSM in comments) is to use `where` to essentially do the same thing as above:

```
In [17]:
df.where(df != -1, df.replace(-1, np.nan).ffill())

Out[17]:
   0  1   2
0  1  2   3
1  4  2   3
2  5  6   3
3  7  8 NaN
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately that would not work if there are nans in addition to the -1 entries in the original Dataeframe. I will edit to show an example.

Comment: See updated answer which should work for your modified example

Comment: Thank you @EdChum, please see the example in the edited question. I believe your edited solution is not suitable for what I had in mind. I do not need to "skip" the nans. I have no interest in what comes after the nans.

Comment: It still works with your example df, see updated answer

Comment: I might write this as `df.where(df != -1, df.replace(-1, np.nan).ffill())`, but it's the same thing.

Comment: You are correct, I missed it at first glance. Thank you kindly

Comment: @DSM yeah another way to skin this cat, I guess it's slightly odd to use the inverse of a mask for the rhs for the assignment but it's understanding that the `ffill` part is the part of interest here